# Split a string and return the unique values

Tags: r, string, unique, strsplit

I have a list of strings like this:

```
D<-c("0,0,0,0,0,0,0", "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,", "0,20,0,0,0,30,0", "0,60,61,70,0,0,","0,1,1,0,0,0,0,")
```

I'd like to end up with a condensed version of this, with only the unique values for each string.

```
D2<-c("0","0","0,20,30","0,60,61,70","0,1")
```

I've tried looping through with a combination of strsplit and unique, but end up with a bunch of NA's.

Comment: `strsplit` and `unique` seems like the go - does `sapply(strsplit(D,","), function(x) paste(unique(x),collapse=",") )` work for your real example? - I don't know how you are getting NA values.

Comment: the second and fourth value ends with "," in the string. That's why the NA appear when you carry out strsplit.

Comment: Your solution works great thelatemail, and worth a correct answer

Comment: @AdamQuek - that's not true - `strsplit("0,0,0,0,0,0,0,", ",")` will not generate a blank or an `NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has attracted already three answers but is about to be closed. The best solution IMHO provided by thelatemail in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461857/split-a-string-and-return-the-unique-values/43464759#comment73979768_43461857) would be missing then:

```
sapply(strsplit(D, ","), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ","))
#[1] "0"          "0"          "0,20,30"    "0,60,61,70" "0,1"
```

#### Data

As given by the OP:

```
D < -c("0,0,0,0,0,0,0", "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,", "0,20,0,0,0,30,0", "0,60,61,70,0,0,","0,1,1,0,0,0,0,")
```

#### Benchmark

A small benchmark

```
library(stringr)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  thelatemail = sapply(strsplit(D, ","), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ",")),
  epi99 = D %>% sapply(str_split, ",")  %>% sapply(unique) %>% sapply(paste, collapse=","),
  trungnt37 = {
    out <- c()
    for(i in 1:length(D)){
      k <- strsplit(x = D[i], split = ",")
      m <- paste(unique(unlist(k)), collapse = ",")
      out <- c(out, m)
    }
    out
  }
)
```

shows that *thelatemail*'s answer is the fastest:

```
#Unit: microseconds
#        expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
# thelatemail  57.770  61.9240  72.63590  67.9655  75.705 151.789   100
#       epi99 318.679 338.5020 383.76284 362.6670 410.054 781.972   100
#   trungnt37  74.384  81.3695  96.77465  87.7885 102.702 240.897   100
```

Note that [*epi99*'s `stringr` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43463942/3817004) doesn't return the expected result as it has trailing commas.

Answer (score 1):

You should use strsplit and unlist function. Try follow code

```
out <- c()

for(i in 1:length(d)){
    k <- strsplit(x = d[i], split = ",")
    m <- paste(unique(unlist(k)), collapse = ",")
    out <- c(out, m)
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I needed `unlist()` as strsplit in my case was converting my output to a list... if anyone knows why it might do this in some cases I'm all ears.

Answer (score -1):

Using the pipe operator %>% which is defined in stringr and other packages

```
library(stringr)
D<-c("0,0,0,0,0,0,0", "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,", "0,20,0,0,0,30,0", "0,60,61,70,0,0,","0,1,1,0,0,0,0,")
result <-  D %>% sapply(strsplit, ",")  %>% sapply(unique) %>% sapply(paste, collapse=",") 

D2<-c("0","0","0,20,30","0,60,61,70","0,1")
all(D2 == result)

# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Please, note that `stringr::str_split()` and `strsplit` differ in the handling of trailing commas: `stringr::str_split("0,", ",")` returns a list with a two element vector `"0", ""` while  `strsplit` returns only one element `"0"`. You have manipulated the input data `D` by removing the trailing commas in order to return the expected result.

Comment: @UweBlock, I should have noted the change. I have reverted to strsplit and the original data